# sql left join query

Tags: sql

Как в этот запрос вставить LEFT JOIN?
Делаю вот так выдает ошибку

```
SELECT
  *
FROM oc_product
WHERE upc='{$value1}' AND price>'{$value2}'
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description
    ON oc_product.product_id=oc_product_description.product_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

только вместо * конкретные поля перечислите из соответствующих таблиц и в WHERE укажите к какой таблице относятся upc и price:

```
SELECT * 
FROM oc_product LEFT JOIN oc_product_description ON oc_product.product_id=oc_product_description.product_id 
WHERE upc='{$value1}' AND price>'{$value2}'
```

Comment: Благодарю это то что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

все источники данных должны идти до условий. Т.е. join должен быть до where

Comment: Благодарю это то что нужно.